# Confusion determining eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix $A$:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    -5 &14& -8 \\
    -9 &16& -6 \\
    -9 &11& -1
\end{bmatrix} $$

Determining eigenvalue of Matrix $A - 1I$ hence $\lambda = 1$ (other eigenvalues are 4 and 5).

Matrix $A - 1I:$ 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    -6 &14& -8 \\
    -9 &15& -6 \\
    -9 &11& -2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$$
**1.** Figuring out each $x_i$ so the above equation complies will give me the eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ right?

**2.** the sum of all $x_i$ must be $0$?

**3.** How would you go about determining $x_i$, do you just play around till you get a right combination?

Comment: Your point 2 is wrong. The sum of $x_i$ is $0$ if the eigenvetor is orthogonal to $(1,1,1)^T$. Actually, here, they are collinear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gaussian elimination, your system is equivalent to the following, writing only the matrix, not the $x_i$ nor the right hand side since there are only zeros in the RHS anyway:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-6 &14& -8 \\
-9 &15& -6 \\
-9 &11& -2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-3 &7& -4 \\
-9 &15& -6 \\
-9 &11& -2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-3 &7& -4 \\
0 &-6& 6 \\
0 &-10& 10
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-3 &7& -4 \\
0 &-6& 6 \\
0 &0& 0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
-3 &7& -4 \\
0 &-6& 6 \\
0 &0& 0
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3
\end{matrix}\right)
=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{matrix}\right)$$

That is, $x_3$ is arbitrary, then $x_2=x_3$ from the second equation, and finally $x_1=-\frac13(4x_3-7x_2)=x_3$.

Therefore, $(1,1,1)^T$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $1$.

When solving such system, if the eigenvalue is correct, you know for sure there is at least one arbitrary component. There are more if the eigenspace has dimension greater than $1$.

Comment: When you write $(1,1,1)^T$, what does the $T$ stand for? The only examples where I have seen the notation $T$ is when speaking about the transpose.

Comment: @coders Yes, the eigenvector is a column vector, so it's the transpose of a row vector. This is a usual trick to save some vertical space.

Comment: Yes that is clever. Say the $3*3$ matrix has only 0's on the bottom 2 rows. and the top row is `|-1 1 1|`, thus $x_1 = x_2 + x_3$. How would you express this in vector form?

Comment: There are then two non-collinear eigenvectors - that is, the eigenspace has dimension two. Then there are two arbitrary parameters, $x_2$ and $x_3$, and two possible eigenvectors would be $(1,0,1)^T$ and $(1,1,0)^T$ (set $x_2=0, x_3=1$ for the first, and $x_2=1,x_3=0$ for the second). Of course, there are infinitely many pairs of eigenvectors, actually any two noncollinear vectors in the plane defined by the above two.

Comment: That makes things very clear, I think I can also deduce that the eigenvalue in $A - 4*I$ (different matrix to above question) which I was working with has multiplicity 2? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @coders The sum of the multiplicities must be the dimension of the space. Here it's 3, and there are three distinct eigenvalues, so each has multiplicity 1, and there will be one parameter for each system. However, bear in mind than even when there is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $k>1$, the eigenspace has dimension **at most** $k$. It can happen that it's actually less.

Comment: @coders For instance, take any upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with only ones on the diagonal, such that $A\neq I_n$. It has then only one eigenvalue (it's $1$), with multiplicity $n$. However, its associated eigenspace can't have dimension $n$. If it where so, there would be a matrix $P$ of eigenvectors (the columns of $P$), and $P$ would be invertible, with $A=PDP^{-1}$. But since $D=I_n$, you would have $A=I_n$. Contradiction. Hence the eigenspace has dimension $<n$ and $A$ is not diagonalizable.